# Copy object properties without using many if statements

Tags: java, classes, form

I have two class:

InputForm.java

```
public class InputForm {
    private String brandCode;
    private String caution;

    public String getBrandCode() {
        return brandCode;
    }

    public void setBrandCode(String brandCode) {
        this.brandCode = brandCode;
    }

    public String getCaution() {
        return caution;
    }
    public void setCaution(String caution) {
        this.caution = caution;
    }
}
```

CopyForm.java

```
public class CopyForm {
    private boolean brandCodeChecked;
    private boolean cautionChecked;

    public boolean isBrandCodeChecked() {
        return brandCodeChecked;
    }

    public void setBrandCodeChecked(boolean brandCodeChecked) {
        this.brandCodeChecked = brandCodeChecked;
    }

    public boolean isCautionChecked() {
        return cautionChecked;
    }

    public void setCautionChecked(boolean cautionChecked) {
        this.cautionChecked = cautionChecked;
    }
}
```

I want to copy values from an InputForm to another if its corresponding property in CopyForm is true.
This is what I do:

```
if(copyForm.isBrandCodeChecked()) {
    inputForm.setBrandCode(otherInputForm.getBrandCode());
}
if(copyForm.isCautionChecked()) {
    inputForm.setCaution(otherInputForm.getCaution());
}
```

The problem is I have many many properties. Writing many if statements seems ugly and bad programming practice.
How to solve it? (I know reflection is not a good choice so I don't think about it)

Comment: Actually reflection came to mind when I read this. I am not very good at Java, so I haven't heard why using it is a bad idea. Why is this so?

Comment: @UwePlonus Nice tip! I've cleared all my erroneus comments. Thank for your help - It may be helpful to keep your last comment for others.

Comment: @cl-r To remove a comment use the red cross beneath your signature.

Answer (score 3):

I think [Apache commons BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/) might help you there. It uses reflection. Take this into consideration if performance is an issue...

We need 2 Steps:

1st create a method that copies a property if a condition is met

2nd create a copy method that passes all fields to the first method

Here we go...

```
public class InputForm {
    [...]

    private void copyProperty(InputForm srcForm, String field, boolean condition) {
        if(condition) {
            PropertyUtils.setProperty(this, field, PropertyUtils.getProperty(srcForm, field));
        }
    }

    public void copyFromOtherForm(InputForm srcForm, CopyForm conditions) {
        copyProperty(srcForm, "brandCode", conditions.isBrandCodeChecked());
        copyProperty(srcForm, "caution", conditions.isCautionChecked());
        [...]
    }
}
```

if you're still not pleased with that you could use reflection to invoke `"is"+field+"Checked"` on your `CopyForm` instance and change the calls to:

```
copyProperty(srcForm, conditions, "field");
```

Comment: Why using an external package when the language offers you what you need already (see my post)?

Answer (score 1):

You may want a static method in your `InputForm` class, named, for instance, `.fromCopyForm()` taking a `CopyForm` as an argument and returning an `InputForm`:

```
public static InputForm fromCopyForm(final CopyForm copyForm)
{
    final InputForm ret = new InputForm();
    // all tests here
    return ret;
}
```

Then in your code:

```
final InputForm form = InputForm.fromCopyForm(copyForm);
```

Comment: where is the magic that fills the fields of the new InputForm depending on the flags in CopyForm?

Comment: Nowhere, why need magic? Just simple checks, written once, that's it; and no reflection needed

Comment: "simple checks" = many if statements = the thing the op wants to get rid of?

Comment: No, simple checks in the static factory method; none where the code is actually _used_.

Comment: so how do you check multiple conditions without multiple ifs?

Comment: That's not the question. The question is, when you need an input form from a copy form, you just `InputForm.fromCopyForm()` and that's it. The code to obtain that input form does not matter; it may even phone the Moon for all it matters.

Comment: i suggest you read the question again...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9197/discussion-between-marco-forberg-and-fge)

Comment: I _did_ read the question. And the OP seems to imply that he creates the new input form by hand. Hence the static factory method proposal that I make.

Comment: In the last part of the question the OP seems to have a **single** method where he creates a new `InputForm` out of the values of another `InputForm` and the flags of the `CopyForm` and asks how to get rid of the myriads of `if`s that he has to do if he has myriads of properties and corresponding flags.